# Deny IPs from dynamically updated text file using htaccess

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

As I read tens of examples or stackoverflow questions and answers I can not find where I am doing wrong. My problem is that, I have a blacklist.txt file containing IPs that will be denied and periodically updated by a php file. By using apache RewriteMap for this text file, I added these commands in my httpd.conf file (by the help of include editor in my whm), added commands in htaccess file in the webroot directory. I have root privilige, using Centos 7 and Apache.

FIle "blacklist.txt" contains:

```
11.22.33.44 deny
555.666.777.888 deny
```

This text file is in a directory /webroot/dir1/dir2/blacklist.txt

The "httpd.conf" file written:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteMap ipm txt:/webroot/dir1/dir2/blacklist.txt
```

The ".htaccess" file on my webroot directory written:

```
RewriteCond ${ipm:%{REMOTE_ADDR}} deny [NC]
RewriteRule ^ - [R=403,L]
```

Does not work as I add my own ip and another ip

additionally changed the "httpd.conf" file written:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteMap ipm "txt:/webroot/dir1/dir2/blacklist.txt"
```

Does not work as I add my own ip and another ip

I tried so many things but unable to achieve deny. Is there anybody who can say what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Are you really sure that `/webroot` is an absolute path to the correct folder? So a path _from the root_ of the physical file system, and not something inside your web folder?

Comment: What does your http server's error log file contain for test requests from addresses you expect to be blocked?

Comment: As I searched for RewriteCond problems in the apache error log file, saw nothing about the RewriteCond for this problem.

Comment: I also wrote the path to text file as /home/user/public_html/dir1/dir2/blacklist.txt

Comment: where user, dir1 and dir2 was replaced by the original values in the system